# Update DataView based on the column value in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, datatable, datatables, linq-to-sql

I have a dataview as below:

```html
Id | GroupName | Count
1    DummyName    1
2    DummyName    1
3    StubName     1
4    DummyName    1
```

I need to update the Count column value for each row based on total number of rows with the same GroupName for that row. The desired output is below:

```html
Id | GroupName | Count
1    DummyName    3
2    DummyName    3
3    StubName     1
4    DummyName    3
```

The logic that I tried to do this with is:

Step 1: Update the Count column value for each row

```html
For Each row As DataRow In tbl.Rows
    row("Count") = From r in tbl _
                   Group r By key = tbl.Columns("sites_siteid") into Group _
                   where Group.Count() > 1
                   Select Group.Count()
Next
```

But it seems like I am messing up with LINQ or ....

I need to do this in VB.Net, I know how to do this in SQL but I am struggling with getting this done in Vb.Net code.
Any help or insight is highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Code is simply an implementation of logic. You can't write code if you don't know what logic it needs to implement. You have provided no indication that you have considered the logic. If you have explain it to us and show us exactly how you have tried to implement it and where you are stuck.

Comment: @jmcilhinney I updated my question to include code that I am trying at my end. Maybe my approach is not correct ;/

Comment: You don't need to use LINQ for this. Look at the `DataTable.Compute` method. It's purpose is to execute an aggregate function, with or without a filter.

Comment: LINQ is for querying, not for updating. You could use a LINQ Query to count the matches, then update each row with a loop. BTW, why does your table have `GroupName` and your code have `sites_siteid`?

Answer (score 0):

First, create a `Dictionary` mapping `sites_siteid` to the count of rows with the same `sites_siteid`:

```
Dim countMap = (From r In tbl.Rows Group r By Key = r.Field(Of String)("sites_siteid") Into Group, Count() Select New With { .SiteId = Key, .Count = Group.Count }) _
                .ToDictionary(Function(ic) ic.SiteId, Function(ic) ic.Count)
```

Then, update each row with the desired count:

```
For Each row As DataRow In tbl.Rows
    row("Count") = countMap(row.Field(Of String)("sites_siteid"))
Next
```